# Quiero multiplicar los elementos de un array con la funcion .map

Tags: array, map

me piden que escriba una funcion mapear en el prototipo del objeto global "array"
que recibe una funcion callBack que se ejecuta por cada elemento del array
y retorna nuevo array con los elementos mapeados.
Yo quiero que los elementos se multipliquen por 2 y este es mi codigo que no me funciona.-

```
//Funcion mapear(){
//var numeros=[2,6,8,7,5];
//numeros.map(funcion(x){
//return x * 2
```

//});

Answer (score 1):

Para poder obtener el resultado debes usar una nueva variable que reciba el return del map

```js
var numbers = [2,6,8,7,5];
var numbersTimes = numbers.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
})

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbersTimes;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```